# EntityDelete ColdFusion EHCache

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, ehcache

How do i delete an Hibernate Entity that is being cached by EHcache and by using Entitydelete in coldfusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the  answer after a whole days worth of effort. Basically if in your EHcache you set diskpresistent =  true, then ColdFusion will not clear the object regardless of if you call evictentity or not.